# C++ Google mock/unit tests : Mock method not called and original one is

Tags: c++, unit-testing, googlemock

I am mocking a method but it seems that my `GoogleTest` keeps calling the original implementation. Probably missing something but can't find out what is this?

My class is a Postgres database accessor:

```
namespace project
{

class PostgresDb
{
public :
    // typedef the CursorPtr, this is just a smart pointer.
    // sth like 
    typedef shared_ptr<DbDataType> CursorPtr ;

    PostgresDb( const std::string & connString ) ;

    CursorPtr getRecords( const int id_1 ,
                          const int id_2 ) ;

protected :

    // this will be used by the MockPostgresDb in our unit tests.
    // it leaves the object uninitialized
     PostgresDb (){} ;

 }

}// end of namespace
```

and here is my mock class:

```
namespace project_test
{

class MockPostgresDb : public project::PostgresDb
{
public :
    MockPostgresDb(){} ;
    MOCK_METHOD2( getRecords, CursorPtr*( const int , const int  ) ) ;
} ;

class MockCursor : public CursorPtr
{
    // ....
}

}
```

and here is the method I am testing and the test:

```
void original_get_method( const int id_1, const int id_2 , PostgresDb db)
{
    // ....
    db.getRecords( id_1, id_2 ) ;
    // ....
}

// helper function
setupGetRecords( MockPostgresDb* db     ,
                 MockCursor*     cursor ) 
{
    EXPECT_CALL( *db, getRecords(_,_) )
        .Times( 1 )
        .WillRepeatedly(::testing::Return( cursor ) ) ;
}


TEST_F(....)
{
    MockPostgresDb db ;
    MockCursor     cursor ;
    // ....
    setupGetRecords( &db, &cursor ) ; 
    // ....
    // and then calling a functi
    original_method( id_1, id_2, db ) ;
}
```

So in my mind, I am calling `original_method` and pass a `mock_db`. The `mock_db` calls its method `getRecords` which returns a `MockCursor`. This is where it should get me the mock one but I do enter the `db::getRecords`.

I am trying to find where the mismatch is but cannot figure out.

EDIT :

So, as pointed out - `getRecords` should return a `CursorPtr` and not a `CursorPtr*`. So here is what I did:

I also tried to change

```
MOCK_METHOD2( getRecords, CursorPtr*( const int , const int  ) ) ;`
```

to

```
MOCK_METHOD2( getRecords, CursorPtr( const int , const int  ) ) ;  // ( no * )
```

And change the helper to

```
// helper function
setupGetRecords( MockPostgresDb* db     ,
                 MockCursor     cursor ) 
{
    EXPECT_CALL( *db, getRecords(_,_) )
        .Times( 1 )
        .WillRepeatedly(::testing::Return( cursor ) ) ;
}
```

and getting some mismatched types of compilation errors. What went wrong? Thanks.

Comment: `getRecords` return object of type `CursorPtr`, and you mock method tries to return `CursorPtr*` Those are two different methods. And what is the meaning of `( no * )`? It seems to be the bit causing compiler errors.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen ok let me retry, but returning CursorPtr gave me lots of compilation errors.

Comment: What kind of compiler errors you get? Please edit the question and add them (copy and paste them, don't paraphrase).

Comment: You have protected `PostgresDb` constructor, are you not creating objects of that class anywhere?

Comment: @Yksisarvinen the public one takes argument a string, the protected is just for the Mock class that uses it. Argument is the environment the db connects to but dont need it for Mock. Editing my answer.

Comment: `Mismatched types errors` don't say much. If possible, copy the exact message (try to filter out gmock macros related ones). I see you try to return `MockCursor` object in function returning `CursorPtr`. What is `MockCursor` and how is it related to `CursorPtr`?

Comment: IIRC, methods mocked should be virtual, if your mock is inheriting from implementation class. Especially destructor (otherwise mock's destructor will not be called).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The main problem here is that in the function `void original_get_method( const int id_1, const int id_2 , PostgresDb db)` the `PostgresDb` is passed by value, i.e. the copy constructor of PostgresDb will be called. This means that inside of the `original_get_method` function you don't have a `MockPostgresDb`-Object but a simple `PostgresDb` and that's why not the mocked method gets called but simply the original implementation. Furthermore the `getRecords` function is not virtual, i.e. the mocked method in class `MockPostgresDb` just shadows the function of `PostgresDb` (and so there's no way to tell the program at run-time which function to call, i.e. if there is a `PostgresDb`-Object or reference to such an object it will always call the function in that class).

So first things to change:

```
class PostgresDb
{
public :
    // typedef the CursorPtr, this is just a smart pointer.
    // sth like 
    typedef shared_ptr<DbDataType> CursorPtr ;

    PostgresDb( const std::string & connString ) ;

    // ===> make this method virtual <====
    virtual CursorPtr getRecords( const int id_1 ,
                          const int id_2 ) ;
}

// pass PostgresDb by reference
void original_get_method( const int id_1, const int id_2 , PostgresDb& db);
```

These two changes will call the mocked method in `original_get_method`.

---

Next problem is as pointed out in the comments:

```
MOCK_METHOD2( getRecords, CursorPtr*( const int , const int  ) ) ;
```

The mock method has a different signature then the base class -> function will not get overwritten in derived (mocked) class (i.e. they are two completely different functions). This is what you want:

```
MOCK_METHOD2( getRecords, CursorPtr( const int , const int  ) ) ;
```

---

Next problem is the following:

```
typedef shared_ptr<DbDataType> CursorPtr ;
```

You define your new type `CursorPtr` and then inherit from it

```
class MockCursor : public CursorPtr {}
```

But `MockCursor` does not inherit from `DbDataType` but from `std::shared_ptr`, i.e. they are nothing alike. Instead let `MockDbDataType` inherit from `DbDataType` and create a new type `MockCursor`:

```
typedef std::shared_ptr<MockDbDataType> MockCursor;
```

And then this should compile fine:

```
setupGetRecords( MockPostgresDb* db     ,
                 MockCursor     cursor ) 
{
    EXPECT_CALL( *db, getRecords(_,_) )
        .Times( 1 )
        .WillRepeatedly(::testing::Return( cursor ) ) ;
}
```

I haven't tested this code, so if there are any problems let me know.